# Stopping Django's Server

Tags: python, django, windows, django-models, command-line

I made a .bat file and using 3rd party app I am running it as a service and in the file the following command :

```
c:\Python27\python.exe manage.py runserver 8003
```

which starts the Django's Server, and I want to stop this running server also using command line to stop the Django Server.
So is there anyway using CMD to stop running server, because I want to automate the whole process beside other stuff.

Comment: You are not supposed to do this sort of thing with the development server

Comment: @e4c5 Well Acutally it a webapp and I need to pull updates to the Git repo, the Process is : Stop there Server, Pull updates, Start the server once again. 
And this should be all automated, but I don't know how to stop the running server

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for a tutorial on creating an automated build process (which is off-topic). But either way you shouldn't be using the development server in production

Comment: @Sayse that is my part of work to do the process, but I am clear with my question. I just need windows command to stop Django servre.

Comment: thanks but I found the answer:

  `  for /f "tokens=5" %a in ('netstat -aon ^| find "8003"') do taskkill /f /pid %a`